# How to remove points from a grid where numeric value is outside the range for its specific factor in R?

Tags: r

Basically, I am trying to remove points on a grid that fall outside the range for its specific factor level.

For example, in the code below I have 2 variables, one numeric and one factor. I then create a grid spanning the range of the data.
Then I find the range of each factor level in the data.

```
# create data
var1 = rnorm(250) 
var2 = as.factor(rep(c("A","B","C", "D", "E"), each = 50))

# create grid
gridvals1 <- seq(min(var1, na.rm = T), max(var1, na.rm = T), length.out = 20)
gridvals2 <- levels(var2)

gridvals <- expand.grid(gridvals1, gridvals2)

# get range of data for each factor level
rangeData <- tapply(var1, var2, range)
```

What Im trying to achieve is to remove any values of `gridvals` that falls outside the range of each factor level (i.e., `rangeData`).

I think `mapply` or something similar should work... but I'm not sure how to achieve this!?

EDIT: So, I found a possible solution... if I add the following code, it seems to work:

```
rangeGrid <- tapply(gridvals$Var1, gridvals$Var2, list)
new_gridvals <- mapply(function(x,y){x[x > y[1] & x < y[2]]}, rangeGrid, rangeData)
new_gridvals <- stack(new_gridvals, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
```

Now `new_gridvals` contains only the grid points that are inside the range of `rangeData` ...

However, this seems quite messy... Is there a cleaner solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data.table` package has the `between()` function for range subsets which can be used here.

```
# create data
set.seed(123)   # IMPORTANT for reproducible results
var1 = rnorm(250) 
var2 = as.factor(rep(c("A","B","C", "D", "E"), each = 50))

# create grid
gridvals1 <- seq(min(var1, na.rm = TRUE), max(var1, na.rm = TRUE), length.out = 20)

# here comes the data.table part
library(data.table)
dt_gridvals <- data.table(var1, var2)[
  , range(var1, na.rm = TRUE), by = var2][
    , gridvals1[between(gridvals1, V1[1L], V1[2L], incbounds = FALSE)], by = var2]
```

For `set.seed(123)`, the result has 71 rows which is too large to be printed here in full but we can show the output of

```
str(dt_gridvals)
```

> ```
> Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':    71 obs. of  2 variables:
>  $ V1  : num  -1.725 -1.433 -1.141 -0.849 -0.556 ...
>  $ var2: Factor w/ 5 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
>  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
> ```

To verify that the result is the same as OP's `new_gridvals` we can use

```
# compare to OP's approach
setcolorder(dt_gridvals, 2:1) # align column order
all.equal(dt_gridvals, new_gridvals, check.attributes = FALSE)
```

> ```
> [1] TRUE
> ```